# Power Apps - replace position of First name and Last name in User().DisplayName

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp, powerapps-forms, powerapps-canvas, formula

My problem is that my `Azure Active Directory` show `DisplayName` attribute as `First name` + `Last name`.

My goal in Power Apps in `Label` text, show `User().DisplayName`  as Last name + First name.

If i use `Concatenante` and `Split` formula:

```
Concatenate(Last(Split(User().DisplayName, " ")), ", ", First(Split(User().DisplayName, " ")))
```

I got this error:

> Invalid argument type (Record). Expecting Text value instead.

Thank you for any advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `Text` property of label control to:

```
Last(Split(User().FullName, " ")).Value & " " & First(Split(User().FullName, " ")).Value
```

**Output**:

[image]